# PHP folder dropdowns

Tags: php, directory, drop-down-menu, filetree

I am trying to make a dropdown menu of folders stored on a site. For example the top level would be a list of folders, and when the user hovers over the folder name, a dropdown appears so the user can see all of the files within. I'm very new to PHP and have tried a few things, but can't get the dropdowns to work. Any suggestions?

**EDIT:** Additional information from comments:

At the moment I'm using [this](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/programming/php-display-a-customizeable-list-of-files-in-a-directory/), which displays the top layer, but it gets the contents of the folders to list in a dropdown, which is the problem. For the first layer I have

```
$thelist .= '<li><a target="frame" href="unzip/uncompressed/'.$file.'">'.$file.'</a></li>';
```

and can display all the contents of all the folders with

```
$thelist2 .= '<li><a target="frame" href="unzip/uncompressed/'.$file.'/'.$file2.'">'.$file2.'</a></li>';
```

I just can't get it to display in dropdowns.

Comment: This is not PHP, it is CSS and/or Javascript. Search Google for a CSS or Javascript drop-down menu

Comment: "im very new to php and have tried a few things but cant get the drop downs to work", Can you show us what you have tried??

Comment: at the moment im using [link](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/programming/php-display-a-customizeable-list-of-files-in-a-directory/) which displays the top layer but its getting the contents of the folders to list in a drop down which is the problem. so i have `$thelist .= '<li><a target="frame" href="unzip/uncompressed/'.$file.'">'.$file.'</a></li>';.`  for the first layer and can display all the contents of all the folders with `$thelist2 .= '<li><a target="frame" href="unzip/uncompressed/'.$file.'/'.$file2.'">'.$file2.'</a></li>';` just cant get it to display in drop downs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [the answer](http://mysocialsnips.com/2/php-2/looping-through-folders-and-creating-secondary-level-menu-menu-system-readdir) myself. Quote:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/1.4.0/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/1.4.0/bootstrap-dropdown.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
<?php 

if ( $handle = opendir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/menu/") ) {
    while(false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
        if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
            $var .= $file . ",";
        }
    }
}

$var = explode(',', $var);

echo " <ul class='tabs'>";
foreach($var as $v){
    if(!preg_match("/php/i", $v)) {
        echo "<li class='dropdown' data-dropdown='dropdown'><a href='" . $v . "' class='dropdown-toggle'>" . $v . "</a><ul class='dropdown-menu'>";
        $folder = $v;
        $t = opendir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/menu/" . $v);
        while(false !== ($v = readdir($t))) {
            if ($v != "." && $v != "..") {
                echo "<li><a href='" . $folder ."/". $v . "'>" . $v . "</a></li>";
            }
        }
        echo "</ul></li>";
    }
} 
echo " </ul>";

?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP could be used to get and output the list of files and folders see : [PHP's Directory Documenation](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dir.php). You would use css/javascript for the styling and user's interaction with the tree.

A quick [google](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=javascript%20css%20directory%20tree) will give you lots of tutorials.